# Kivy Grabbing Touch without Delay

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to implement touchtracer demo example into my code.
[Here is the original page](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__demo__touchtracer__main__py.html)

I realized that the tracing does only work with a delay (after you press and hold the button) due to the necessary *touch.grab(self)* event. However, I want to see the trace without the delay, immediately after the first move. Is there any way to do that without disturbing the trace making?

EDIT: By 'delay', I mean the holding action to activate the tracing. Currently a press + hold is needed to start the tracer. I want to be able to trace on the go, without the 'hold'.

EDIT2: I felt the need to explain how my version of touchtracer differs with everyone else's because no-one seems to face this problem except me. I embedded touchtracer code in mine and removed the vertical/horizontal lines and the label. So my version only has the trace. Here is what my on_touch_down, on_touch_move and on_touch_up looks like.

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    win = self.get_parent_window()
    ud = touch.ud
    ud['group'] = g = str(touch.uid)
    pointsize = 5
    ud['color'] = random()

    with self.canvas:
        Color(ud['color'], 1, 1, mode='hsv', group=g)
        ud['lines'] = [
            Point(points=(touch.x, touch.y), source='particle.png',
                  pointsize=pointsize, group=g)]
    touch.grab(self)
    return True

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.grab_current is not self:
        return
    ud = touch.ud
    index = -1
    while True:
        try:
            points = ud['lines'][index].points
            oldx, oldy = points[-2], points[-1]
            break
        except:
            index -= 1

    if (oldx, oldy) == (touch.x, touch.y):
        return

    points = calculate_points(oldx, oldy, touch.x, touch.y)

    if points:
        try:
            lp = ud['lines'][-1].add_point
            for idx in range(0, len(points), 2):
                lp(points[idx], points[idx + 1])
        except GraphicException:
            pass

def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if touch.grab_current is not self:
        return
    touch.ungrab(self)
    ud = touch.ud
    self.canvas.remove_group(ud['group'])
```

Comment: Just downloaded this example and can't experience any delay between drawing traces and pressing a mouse button. Used kivy 1.9.2 dev with python 2.7

Comment: I'm fairly sure this example should introduce no appreciable delay. Does the same thing happen in other Kivy apps, and does it go away if you remove the `touch.grab` call?

Comment: The delay I was talking about was the 'press and hold' activation of the tracer. It does not work if I move the pointer with the left-click action. I am using python 2.7 and kivy 1.9.1 and without grabbing the trace does not work.

Comment: @potato Do you experience [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4425)?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Not really. But your post made me realize that maybe it is the case that trace does not work without having a certain number of items in the touch list. Since no one else seems to face the same problem as I did, I wonder if it is because the changes I made to the system. I edited my question to expain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it looked like a version problem with one of the libraries. I used this in python2.7 built on Ubuntu 14.0 running on a virtualbox. I updated everything related to python and re-installed kivy with libraries and the problem is fixed. I am still not sure what caused it since I did not receive any error messages in the log, but looks like it was due to a bug or not-properly-installed kivy.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I got it now! So you want to draw on hover - without a need to press the button - like html/css `:hover`, right?

There was a guy who made a behavior for that, but [that file](https://gist.github.com/opqopq/15c707dc4cffc2b6455f)(+ [backup](https://gist.github.com/KeyWeeUsr/3166f13d363d5558f481d538c6a5d2aa) in case it'd disappear) is LGPL, so I'm not sure how you should treat it. However, I'm definitely sure a license can't forbid you to do a basic operation the *framework* allows you to do, so... take it apart and you're good to go I think.

Comment: Not really, I want to use the tracing that is activated via click. It just does not start tracing right away, I think it is due to the fact that I removed the labels and the lines that show x/y axes.

Comment: Would you mind to provide a video? I don't really understand what do you mean if it's not hover or the issue I created. Maybe it's only a glitch on your pc or something. I think touchtracer works normally(except the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, it turns out that "ScrollView" and all its children have a built in delay to check if it is a fast touch or a drag, you can fix this by manually setting the delay to zero :

```
yourScrollView.scroll_timeout = 0
```